# How to broadcast np.take_along_axis?

Tags: python, numpy

My objective is to sort `Y` first (increasing, from 0 to 3), then sort the `X` according to the sorted `Y`. Note that `X` and `Y` are one to one.

```py
Y = np.random.randint(0, 4, (2, 10,))
print("before Y", Y.shape) # before Y (2, 10)
print(Y)
print()

idx = np.argsort(Y, axis=1)

Y_ordered = np.take_along_axis(Y, idx, axis=1)
print("reordered Y", Y_ordered.shape) # reordered Y (2, 10)
print(Y_ordered)
print()

### 

X = np.random.rand(2, 10, 64, 64)

X_ordered = np.take_along_axis(X, idx, axis=1) # ValueError: `indices` and `arr` must have the same number of dimensions
print("reordered X", X_ordered.shape)
print(X_ordered)
print()
```

I got the `Y_ordered` that I want, but how to broadcast the same `idx` on another array `X` with different shape, but have the same size in the first 2 dimensions.

Comment: I have added 2 `idx = np.expand_dims(idx, 3)`, seems might have solved this problem.

Comment: X_ordered = np.take_along_axis(X, idx[:,:,None,None], axis=1)

Comment: @MBeale Please don't post answers as comments.